# Блокировка единственной записи таблицы

Tags: sql-server

Ms SQL Server 2019. Необходимо при чтении заблокировать строку, но блокируется вся таблица:

```sql
begin transaction

select * from <table> with (XLOCK,READPAST) where id = 3

commit transaction
```

Хотя READPAST позволяет другим сеансам выполнять тот же SELECT, но с другими строками. Пробовал использовать и ROWLOCK - результат тот же. Как можно реализовать блокировку одной записи?

Comment: Добрый день. Как использовали ROWLOCK?

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял вас беспокоит то, что другие сеансы имеют возможность SELECTа к заблокированной строке?

Comment: @Yallz, ```select * from <table> with (ROWLOCK,READPAST) where id = 3```.
Нет, проблема в том, что блокируется вся таблица, а не выбранная строка

Comment: А на id есть индекс? И если есть, то какой: уникальный или не уникальный, кластерный или не кластерный?

Comment: @i-one, id - PK таблицы

Comment: Тогда `WITH (ROWLOCK, XLOCK, FORCESEEK)`, по-идее, должно сработать. Нужен ли `READPAST` - зависит от логики. Поведение с ним и без него будет разное.